# How to extend range of a wireless router for an outdoor area that doesn't have electrical outlets

Tags: wireless-router

I am looking for a wireless router than has a range of at least 50 yards.  I am trying to get access to an outdoor area where there are no power outlets to plug in an extender.  I am wondering if anyone knows of a way to achieve this.  I am currently using a cisco e2500 router.

Comment: If you can't plug in an extender, your only option is to install better/stronger antennae at each end of the space, or orient the one(s) you have differently.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your best bet is to use a normal router, but upgrade the antenna. You'll need a router with a detachable antenna and/or external connector.

With a short extension cable you could have an antenna physically located outdoors, but connected to the router indoors.

Sites such as http://www.wifi-antennas.co.uk/ (top search result for "wifi antennas") will give you some ideas of what's available, and even has a link to a [connector lookup table](http://www.allendale-stores.co.uk/wifi/info/connector_lookup_tables.html).